# Cannot access Chocolatey package from Azure DevOps Artifact Feed

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, chocolatey

The flowing code has been pushed to an Azure DevOps Artifacts Feed:

[schily-cdrtools](https://github.com/TyMac/schily-cdrtools)

Pushing the nuget package and downloading work without issues using nuget.exe:

```
nuget.exe push -Source "cdrtools-artifacts" -ApiKey AzureDevOps schily-cdrtools.3.2.1.nupkg

nuget.exe install -Source "cdrtools-artifacts" schily-cdrtools
```

However, attempting to register this source with Chocolatey results in a 404 error using either a v2 or v3 nuget registration:

```
choco source add -n=schily-artifacts `
>>    -s="https://flapjacks.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/schily-artifacts/nuget/v3/index.json" `
>>    -u="xxxxxxxx" -p="xxxxxxxxxxx"

 Error retrieving packages from source 'https://flapjacks.visualstudio.com/_packaging/schily-artifacts/nuget/v3/index.json':
 The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
 schily-cdrtools not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://flapjacks.visualstudio.com/_packaging/schily-artifacts/nuget/v3/index.json'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
 If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
 Please see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.
```

...and the same 404 error when using v2:

```
choco source add -n=schily-artifacts `
>>    -s="https://flapjacks.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/schily-artifacts/nuget/v2" `
>>    -u="xxxxxxxx" -p="xxxxxxx"
```

Trying to list with the v2 registration comes up with no packages found, however when running choco list with the v3 it comes back with a 404 error.

Finally, trying with Install-Package failes with a credentials issue:

```
Install-Package schily-cdrtools
WARNING: Cannot access 'https://flapjacks.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/schily-artifacts/nuget/v3/index.json'. Are you missing 'Credential' parameter in the cmdlet?

Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'schily-cdrtools'. Try Get-Packa
geSource to see all available registered package sources.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package schily-cdrtools
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.PowerShel\u2026lets.InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package
], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Any ideas no what I'm missing?

I've been using the following as a guide:

https://blog.pauby.com/post/chocolatey-repository-using-azure-devops-artifacts-feed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot access Chocolatey package from Azure DevOps Artifact Feed

I could not reproduce this issue after created a sample based on the steps in that guide. But I would like provide some troubleshooting to you:

1. Check your Chocolatey version, mine is `Chocolatey v0.10.15`.
2. Use PAT instead of password when you add Chocolatey Azure DevOps Feed named source.
3. Run the command line with Administrator.
4. The command line should be complete and does not require a branch, like:

   ```
   choco source add -n=MyCustomFeed -s="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<MyOrgName>/_packaging/<FeedName>/nuget/v2" -u="MyAccount.com" -p="PAT"
   ```

My Test Result:

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you this works to list the package after upload. choco install <package> does the same when supplied the -s -u -p switches as above.

Answer (score 0):

The PackageManagement cmdlets are broken currently so using `Install-Package` without the `-Credential` parameter will fail. You need to add the `-Credential` parameter to all of the PackageManagement cmdlets for them to work.

If I run (*exactly*):

```
choco source add -n=schily-artifacts -s="https://flapjacks.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/schily-artifacts/nuget/v2" -u="xxxxxxxx" -p="xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Then I get:

```
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Added schily-artifacts - https://flapjacks.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/schily-artifacts/nuget/v2 (Priority 0)
```

Chocolatey doesn't validate the feed until you use it:

```
choco list --source=schily-artifacts
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
[NuGet] Not able to contact source 'https://flapjacks.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/schily-artifacts/nuget/v2'. Error was The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
Invalid credentials specified.
[NuGet] Not able to contact source 'https://flapjacks.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/schily-artifacts/nuget/v2'. Error was The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
0 packages found.
```

Which is what I'd expect (as the credentials are invalid). So I'm not sure where your errors are coming from when adding the source.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with **Credential Provider**, slightly modified version of the script that was publish in [github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1721](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1721#issuecomment-810558523) (last lines were changed to use `choco` instead of `nuget` command).

The script runs a Credential Provider (which prompts you to login to Azure DevOps and automatically generate a PAT). The returned PAT is used with the same choco command as in [Leo Liu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57851712/6812182)

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$feedName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$url
)

$profilePath = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::UserProfile)
$pluginLocation = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($profilePath, ".nuget", "plugins");
$localNetfxCredProviderPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine("netfx", "CredentialProvider.Microsoft");
$fullNetfxCredProviderPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($pluginLocation, $localNetfxCredProviderPath)
$netfxExists = Test-Path -Path ($fullNetfxCredProviderPath)

if($netfxExists -eq $false)
{
    Write-Host "Installing credential provider..."
    iex "& { $(irm https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.ps1) } -AddNetfx"

    $netfxExists = Test-Path -Path ($fullNetfxCredProviderPath)
    if($netfxExists -eq $false)
    {
        Write-Host "Credentials provider is required."
        Write-Host "Maybe install manually from https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/releases"
        return
    }
}

$exe = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($fullNetfxCredProviderPath, 'CredentialProvider.Microsoft.exe')
# It's not possible to disable device based authentication, but we can set timeout to fail immidiately.
$ENV:NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_VSTS_DEVICEFLOWTIMEOUTSECONDS=0
# Validity period: 1 year. (Can have larger value)
$ENV:NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_VSTS_SESSIONTIMEMINUTES=365*24*60
# '-V Error' is required not to get extra messages
$msg = & $exe -V Error -U $url -C -F JSON 2>&1 | Out-String

if($lastexitcode -ne 0)
{
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "$msg"
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Failed to run '$exe' ($lastexitcode)"
    return
}

try
{
    $info = ConvertFrom-Json $msg
}
catch
{
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "$msg"
    Write-Host
    return
}

choco source add -v -n="$feedName" -s="$url" -u "$($info.Username)" -p="$($info.Password)"
```